# Why does my weapon switch to non-automatic in Battlefield 3?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3

I don't know if I am accidentally hitting a button and not knowing it, missing a feature that I didn't read about, or keep hitting a bug that hasn't been fixed - but my guns sometimes are no longer automatic.

I am still rather new, and these are using whatever the default guns are for each class.

I will be playing, and the gun is automatic, as in, I hold the trigger button (RT) down and shoot several bullets. This is the way I would always expect it to work, unless I was using a weapon I knew was non-automaic, like a sniper rifle or basic handgun.

Every once in a while though, usually after a respawn or revive, but also after changing from a vehicle back to non-vehicle, the weapon will go into a non-automatic mode. As in, if I hold down the trigger, only one bullet comes out until I press the trigger again.

I know my weapon hasn't changed, nor my class - its the same weapon. But suddenly it is no longer automatic.

This will even last through respawns, and class changes. For example, if I am support, then engineer, the next 'what should be automatic weapon' is not. But then, suddenly it will be maybe after another respawn, etc.

I can not pinpoint why this happens. I don't know if I end up hitting a certain button not knowing it (I have sometimes accidentally changed classes waiting to respawn not knowing it). What is causing this? Can you turn on/off the automatic setting on weapons in BF3? Is this some glitch?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can go from semi-automatic to fully automatic by pressing down on the D-Pad, but it has been over a year since I last played. I could be mistaken.

Comment: It looks like you are right, and that actually makes a bit of sense - I usually go as support, and throw out a lot of ammo. I could keep accidentally hitting down as well. If you can, could you make your comment an answer?

Comment: On a side note, semi automatic kicks ass when firing from longer rages.

Comment: On the AN-94 it goes to Burst as soon as you spawn the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a few weapons in the game feature both automatic and semi-automatic firing.

To switch between the two, you simply press <kbd>↓</kbd> on the D-pad. Given the poor design of the Xbox 360 D-Pad, it is very possible that you are (and you've already stated this) accidentally hitting down as you are also hitting left or right to toggle between the varying kit tools (ammo, rockets/mines, grenade launcher).

If you find yourself firing a single shot when you feel you should instead be firing fully automatic, try hitting down again.

Comment: Additionally, the selected fire mode will persist through multiple respawns

Comment: Additionally, in bottom right, next to ammo counter, there is a visual representation of firing mode. It is good practice to keep an eye on it, while switching back to gun.

Comment: The visual representation `jitendra garg` is mentioning is; 1 Dot for Single, 2 dots for Semi-Automatic and 3 dots for Fully-Automatic.